# Long to Hex VB6, recode in c#

Tags: c#, vb6, hex, long-integer

I want to code this part of a VB6 application in c#.
How can I change a long into a Hex value?

```
Public Function longToHex(l As Long) As String
    longToHex = Hex(l)
    If Len(longToHex) < 4 Then longToHex = String(4 - Len(longToHex), "0") & longToHex
    longToHex = Right(longToHex, 2) & Left(longToHex, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Did you look at the VB6 documentation. E.g. [Hex function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445020(v=vs.60).aspx)  [Left function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445061(v=vs.60).aspx) [String function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263374(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just format to a padded hex string:

```
string.Format("{0:X4}", myLong.ToString().Length / 2)
```

Then transpose the first two characters with the last two.

The VB6 code appears to take the length of `sData` divided by 2, then converts the length to a Hex string and pads it with 0s to 4 characters if needed. It then transposes the first two characters with the last two.

Comment: This is not working I have to get the long throu this. I get the Length of sData in a long and put it into a string. I mean if I divide the length of sData("12345") I'll get 2,5, but 2 would be right.

Comment: @Noli - You are incorrect. In C# if you do `5 / 2`, you will get `2`. It is called [Integer Division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

Comment: Oh I am realy sorry I see now. I was not able to handle that this was I thought it is. Now I got the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Seems convoluted -- what is the code supposed to do? Half the length of the string in hex? 
This might work:  `sLen = (sData.length / 2).ToString("X")`